# What code smell best describes this code?

Tags: code-quality, code-smell, coupling

Suppose you have this code in a class:

```java
private DataContext _context;

public Customer[] GetCustomers() 
{
    GetContext();

    return _context.Customers.ToArray();
}

public Order[] GetOrders() 
{
    GetContext();

    return _context.Customers.ToArray();
}

// For the sake of this example, a new DataContext is *required* 
// for every public method call
private void GetContext()
{
    if (_context != null) 
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    _context = new DataContext();
}
```

This code isn't thread-safe - if two calls to `GetOrders`/`GetCustomers` are made at the same time from different threads, they may end up using the same context, or the context could be disposed while being used. Even if this bug didn't exist, however, it still "smells" like bad code.

A much better design would be for `GetContext` to always return a new instance of `DataContext` and to get rid of the private field, and to dispose of the instance when done. Changing from an inappropriate private field to a local variable feels like a better solution.

I've looked over the code smell lists and can't find one that describes this. In the past I've thought of it as [temporal coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)), but the Wikipedia description suggests that's not the term:

> *Temporal coupling*
>   When two actions are bundled together into one module just because they happen to occur at the same time.

[This page discusses temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling.aspx), but the example is the public API of a class, while my question is about the internal design.

Does this smell have a name? Or is it simply "buggy code"?

Comment: in getContext method, did you mean to check for `_context == null` to dispose? I would expect an opposite - checking for not-null prior to disposing

Comment: What is this code trying to achieve?

Comment: FWIW, those two definitions of temporal coupling are at odds.  I have always thought temporal coupling was defined as described in the ploeh (Mark Seeman) link (I realize that has nothing to do with your question per se . . .).

Comment: *Does this smell have a name? Or is it simply "buggy code"?* I think I would just call it buggy code.  It almost a race condition, but I'm not sure I would call it that either.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a catchy name for it, but I'd say that that code "relies on [side-effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29)" - `GetContext()` isn't actually *getting* anything, it's changing something way off *over there* that affects how subsequent code will run.

That said, this code smell can evolve into an antipattern called [sequential coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling).  The difference is that the antipattern usually applies to calls from outside the object, rather than inside.

Sequential coupling usually manifests more like this:

```
obj = Cls()
obj.Start()
obj.LoadParams()
obj.InitEviron()
obj.Run()
```

where running these in a different order (or omitting one) would produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

If you really *must* instantiate the context in every call (I dont know why you would need to do this) then make it explicit

```
public Customer[] GetCustomers() 
{
    using (var context = new DBContext())
    {
         return context.Customers.ToArray();
    }
}

public Order[] GetOrders() 
{
    using (var context = new DBContext())
    {
        return context.Customers.ToArray();
    }
}
```

That still isn't perfect code as it's tightly bound to the DBContext class and impossibly to isolate for unit testing

Answer (score 0):

Its just buggy code.

```
    if (_context == null) 
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
```

If ever _context == null then you will be calling a method on a null object so it will just fall over. There is no reason to reinstanciate the datacontext for every call.

Comment: Thanks, that was a bug in the sample that I've fixed. Is it "perfect code" now that the `==` is a `!=`?

Comment: No. re-instantiating the datacontext in every call is wastefull. At least it wont fall over now though

Comment: In this example (for the sake of the example) creating a new DataContext every call is a requirement.